# Single .py file install to /python2.7/site-packages using setuptools

Tags: setuptools, conda, setup.py

This question seems almost too trivial to need to ask, but I can't find any resources that spell it out for me:

I am trying to import a SINGLE .py (named ExpData.py) file into a machine's .../python2.7/site-packages directory, using a setup.py file. Here is the setup.py file:

```
from setuptools import setup 

setup(name='ExpData',
  py_modules=['ExpData'],
  )
```

ExpData.py is in the same directory as the setup.py file. To the best of my understanding, executing

```
python setup.py install
```

should place the file into the site-packages directory like I want it to, but when I look in the directory after the install, the only ExpDat file is called ExpData-0.0.0-py2.7.egg.

This python install is inside of a conda package installation, and I am trying to execute the

```
python setup.py install
```

command inside of the conda recipe's build.sh file. I suspect this has something to do with the problem, but I don't know any other way of executing the python setup install. Any and all advice is appreciated.

Comment: You need at least an `__init__.py` file to indicate to Python that this is a package. Also, I'd recommend putting the python script to be installed into its own directory with the same name as the package. See here for a sample directory structure: https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject

Comment: Thank you very much! I did some googling around on the    __init__.py    file and I think I have a better understanding of how to proceed. I appreciate the response!